# Kivy TextInput field throwing missing background color error

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to familiarize myself with some basic Kivy GUI building, and am trying to create a TextField that a user enters some text and it changes a label when they press Return.

My code:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label



class textInput(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(textInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.label = Label(text = 'No text')
        self.textSpace = TextInput(pos = (300,300), text = 'Type here', multiline = False, on_enter = changeText())

        self.orientation = 'horizontal'
        self.size = (450,300)

        self.add_widget(label)
        self.add_widget(textSpace)

    def changeText(value):
        self.textSpace.text = value

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return textInput()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()
```

Trying to execute the code from terminal, I receive the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1649, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kivy/data/style.kv", line 167, in <module>
     rgba: self.background_color
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 19, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__ (/var/folders/yx/bvym8vps2sd_0q19bxy2ddfw0000gn/T/pip-xjpmjrk9-build/kivy/weakproxy.c:1101)
 AttributeError: 'textInput' object has no attribute 'background_color'
```

I attempted to find some tutorials on TextInput, and none of them have anything setting a background color on the widget.

I have attempted to give it a background color without success.  I tried a different layout type (Grid Layout) with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the class name `textInput` causes problems. Class names should be capitalized anyway, and I suggest putting 'my' in front of the names you choose, so how about `MyTextWidget`?

The second major problem is: there is no `on_enter` event for a `TextInput` widget.  It's apparent you read the docs about TextInput's because the docs assign a function to the TextInput's `on_text_validate` event(which fires when you hit Enter), and the name the docs used for their event handler function was...on_enter. Confusing at best, but the event name is `on_text_validate`, so you need to assign your function to that event.  The docs should have named their event handler function something like `my_func` instead of `on_enter`.

Also, when you assign a function to an event, you are not the one that is calling the function, rather kivy will call the function at some time in the future, so you don't want to do this:

```
def do_stuff():
    return 'hello'

on_text_validate = do_stuff()  #Calls function now!
```

The reason is: all function calls in your code are replaced by the function's return value (and a function returns None by default if there is no return statement), so the above is equivalent to writing:

```
on_text_validate = "hello"
```

Later, kivy is going to call whatever was assigned to `on_text_validate` as if it were a function:

```
on_text_validate(..)
```

which will produce the error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What you want to do is: assign just the `function name` to `on_text_validate`:

```
def do_stuff():
    print 'hello'

on_text_validate = do_stuff  #Function does not execute without the trailing: ()

#Time passes...

on_text_validate(...)  #kivy will do this after the user hits Enter in the TextInput

--output:--
hello
```

That is just normal python, which means it's normal to do the following:

```
def do_stuff():
    print 'hello'

f = do_stuff
f()  #=> hello
```

And, more useful:

```
              +-----+                 +-----+
   func=greet |     |       x="hello" |     |
              V     |                 V     |
def do_stuff(func): |        def show(x):   |
    func()          |            print x    |  
    print 'world'   |                       |
                    |                       |
def greet():        |                       |
    print 'hello'   |                       |
                    |                 +-----+
           +--------+                 |
           |                          |
do_stuff(greet)               show('hello')

--output:-                    --output:--
hello                         hello
world
```

And as @inclement pointed out, there are other problems with your code.  See comments below:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyTextWidget(FloatLayout):  #Capitalization here
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyTextWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs) #Capitalization here

        self.label = Label(text = 'No text')

        self.textSpace = TextInput(
            pos = (20, 20),  #The top of the TextInput is off the screen
            text = 'Type here', 
            multiline = False, 
            on_text_validate = self.changeText  #You assign the function name here
        )


        self.orientation = 'horizontal'
        self.size = (450,300)

        self.add_widget(self.label)  #Nowhere in your code is there a variable 
                                     #named label
        self.add_widget(self.textSpace)  #Nowhere in your code is there 
                                         #a variable named textSpace

    def changeText(self, textInput):
        self.textSpace.text = textInput.text + ": is what you entered"

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyTextWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()
```

Note that because you do not call the function that you assign to an event, you are not able to specify the arguments.  If you specify the arguments, for example

```
on_validate_text = do_stuff('hello', 10)
```

then the function executes immediately and the return value of the function is assigned to on_validate_text.   That presents a problem: how are you supposed to define your function?  Should it take one argument? Two arguments?  kivy is going to call your function like this:

```
on_validate_text(arg1, arg2..., argn)
```

So you have to read the docs to know how many arguments kivy will specify when it calls your event handler function.  Or, if the docs are inadequate you can do this:

```
def do_stuff(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print arg
...
...

 on_text_validate = do_stuff
```

And then examine the output.

Comment: This was it, I appreciate the write up!  It is very confusing that their documentation uses the "on_enter" name for their function, and you are right in saying that is what got me. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a name clash problem - I'm not sure why, but your textInput is trying to apply the TextInput kv rule. Maybe there's a `.lower()` in there somewhere. You could just rename the class, it's not good style to have the same name (up to case) anyway.

You also have several problems where you do e.g. `self.add_widget(label)` when there is no variable `label` because you mean `self.label`.